# How can I link to a script in a different page?

Tags: javascript, html

If I have a HTML document such as:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <!-- title, style, etc. -->
</head>
<body>
    <p id="content">Content</p>
    <button onclick="">Change Content</button>
</body>
```

is it possible to link to a script in a different HTML document (notice the `<script>` tag in the head of the document):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <!-- title, style etc. -->
    <script>
        function changeContent() {
            document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = "New Content";
        };
    <script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- content -->
</body>
```

So that the `onclick` of the button in the body of the first document can be changed to `"changeContent()"` without putting the `changeContent()` function in the head of the first document?

**EDIT:**
What if the first document was within an `<iframe>`?

Answer (score 1):

You can add the function to a separate JavaScript file that is linked (by using a script tag with a src attribute) from both html files.

Otherwise, the function will not be defined in your current page.

Comment: The problem is that I cannot do that.

Comment: @BobTheAwesome and why cant you do that?

Comment: It might be interesting to see if, if you put that entire other html file url as the src of the script tag, the function gets defined in your page. I've never tried that. But it does seem like it would be simpler to copy the function locally.

Comment: what about getting the content of a other page... i know its kind of dirty but  he could get the content and than strip it down to the script part and add it kind of "dynamically"

Comment: @F.Müller I am limited to only HTML documents (I have no way of saving Javascript files).

Comment: I need this because I will be changing the function over time and many documents will be using it, and it would not be practical at all to copy the function to all the documents using it every time I change it.

Comment: Can you save an"html" file that doesn't actually have html elements in it but only contains JavaScript? Because when you use a script tag with a src it doesn't care about the extension of the file, just the contents.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is, you could get the content of the page (the page with the js) if its not on your server. Otherwise you could load a external js file like:

```
var imported = document.createElement('script');
imported.src = '/path/to/imported/script';
document.head.appendChild(imported);
```

depending if the file is on your server or not...

If its on a external server you could try to get the content and cut everyting of whats before `<script>` and after `</script>` whats actually kind of dirty but I think its possible. Than you could create a temp script dynamically like sample above... and than use the click...

Propably easier with jquery. You also need to use ajax in this case :)

Answer (score 0):

I have tested the following:

**HTML-File 1 (test_1.html)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <!-- title, style, etc. -->
    <script src="test_2.html"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="content">Content</p>
    <button onclick="changeContent()">Change Content</button>
</body>
```

**HTML-File 2 (test_2.html)**

```
function changeContent() {
  document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = "New Content";
};
```

Well, it is not a clean solution but in this case it does actually work.

*Note: All I did was to include a `.html` file instead of a `.js` file. And you can only use non-html syntax in this `test_2.html` document.*

Comment: Ok, this solves _part_ of the problem... But what if the first document was within an `<iframe>`?

Comment: then you have to include the test_2.html file in the iframe source file.

Comment: @BobTheAwesome why would you do this? you asked for "how to load a js code from a html page into another html page" the behaviour in my solution is almost equal to a real js file and you don't want to have an iframe in a js file do you?

Comment: The first page (without the function) in a plain html file. The second page (with the function) is contained in a page on the server by way of `<iframe>`.